# How to immediately update variable initialized from asynchronous FileReader function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, filereader

I am trying to save content of a csv file into a variable using FileReader. I managed to get the content and saved it into the variable csvAreas but it is not immediately updated. I've tried doing **callback method** and **jquery $.when().then()** but it still not working.

**test.csv:**

```
c1,23.44308893,53.06396484
c2,23.73506919,54.0637207
c3,23.01907619,53.12988281
```

**main.js:**

```
var csvAreas = [];

// other stuff..

function csvImport(){
    $.when(csvLoad()).then(drawCSVCoverage());
}

function csvLoad(){
    var file = document.getElementById("csv-file-upload").files[0];

    readFile(file, function(e) {
        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            var cols = lines[line].split(',');
            csvAreas.push([]);
            csvAreas[line].push(cols[1]);
            csvAreas[line].push(cols[2]);
        }
    });
}

function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function drawCSVCoverage(){
    alert("Length: " + csvAreas.length) //Length: 0
}
```

However, if I alert the second time, `alert(csvAreas.length)` will produce the real value.

```
function drawCSVCoverage(){
    alert("Length: " + csvAreas.length) //Length: 0
    alert("Length: " + csvAreas.length) //Length: 3
}
```

Does alert cause the browser to update the variable? Is there any proper way to update the variable?

Comment: Your `csvLoad` function must return a `Deferred` object in order to be a sensible argument to `when`. Also, the argument to `then` should be a function; instead you are immediately calling `drawCSVCoverage` and passing the return value into `then`. (i.e., lose the `()` on `drawCSVCoverage()`)

Comment: I'm guessing that `drawCSVCoverage()` executes before `csvLoad()` completes.

Comment: you can do a simple test to make sure it's executing before, like @Marc said, with this: `setTimeout(function(){alert("Length: " + csvAreas.length);},4000)`

Comment: @Marc I think so too. I set 50 ms timeout before executing drawCSVCoverage() and it kinda solve the problem. Do you think it's a legit way?

Comment: @CaioCésarS.Leonardi yes tested it with 50 ms delay between the execution of drawCSVCoverage and csvLoad and it produce the correct value. So, is that the proper way to execute function that rely on previous asynchronous function?

Comment: @nyamuk91 I wouldn't say it's the proper way, but with this, you at least know what's going on. From there, you need to think of a way to assure that the variable will only be used after the completion of the async task. I don't really know if this is the "legit" way, but it works fine for me =)

Comment: The proper way is to do what @apsillers recommends, which is to return a `Deferred` object. Presumably you're using jQuery since this question is tagged as such, so start by looking here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/